# Laravel - Unique Rules for multiple columns in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Kindly pardon me, I just started using Laravel Unique Rules

I have this table in Laravel-5.8:

exams: id, exam_category_id, exam_name, exam_year, student_id

Model class is Exam and the route in route list is exam

> exam_category_id, exam_name, exam_year, student_id are uniquely tied together. Four of them are together

```
public function rules()
{
   ....
}
```

This is not working:

> Rule::unique('exams', 'exam_category_id', 'exam_name', 'exam_year', 'student_id')

```
        'exam_category_id' => [
           'required',              
           Rule::unique('exams', 'exam_category_id', 'exam_name', 'exam_year', 'student_id')
        ],
```

Once you entered it, it won't allow any other student with the same ;'exam_category_id', 'exam_name', 'exam_year'

I have only used unique rule for one column. How can I make the four (4) columns to be unique together both for create and update?

Thank you.